# Showing that a power series is bounded

Tags: analysis, inequality, power-series

Let $\sum a_nx^n$ be a power series with a radius of convergence of $2$. Then there exists an $M$ such that

$$\left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n\right\rvert \le M\left\lvert x \right\rvert$$

where $\left\lvert x \right\rvert \le 1$

The constant term is $0$.

I'm not sure where to exactly to start. I've tried showing the series is bounded and attempted to rearrange the expression into the given form, but that was not successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{n-1}$ also has radius of convergence $2$. Hence $g$ is analytic, in particular continuous, for $|x| \leq 1$. Since continuous functions are bounded on compact sets there exists $M <\infty$ such that $|g(x)| \leq M$ for $|x| \leq 1$. Hence $|f(x)|=|xg(x)| \leq M|x|$ for $|x| \leq 1$.

Comment: I see, thank you!