# Bound power series where each term is divided by $n!$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, exponential-function

Suppose the radius of convergence, $R$, of the power series $\sum_0^\infty c_nz^n$ has a positive radius of convergence. How can I show that
$$\left| \sum_{1}^\infty \frac{c_nz^n}{n!} \right| \le C \cdot e^{|z|/R}$$
for some positive constant $C$?

I am thinking we're supposed to use the complex power series expansion of $e^z = \sum_0^\infty \frac{z^k}{n!} = e^z$. I was thinking I could make a similar argument to the one made in this post [Showing that a power series is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097253/showing-that-a-power-series-is-bounded) and multiply by something like $e^z$ instead of x (in the post). How am I supposed to use the fact that the power series $\sum_0^\infty c_nz^n$ has a positive radius of convergence?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Let $0<R_0<R$. Then by the convergence of the given series at any $z$ with $|z|=R_0$,  $c_n R_0^n\to 0$, so there exists $\epsilon(n)\to 0$ such that $c_n \le \epsilon(n) R_0^{-n}$, in particular there exists $C>0$ such that $c_n \le CR_0^{-n}$. Plug in: 

$$\left| \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_nz^n}{n!} \right|\le C\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{|z/R_0|^n}{n!} = Ce^{|z|/R_0}.$$This is not quite the result

Comment: In the linked post, there is also the shrinking of the radius (from 2 in the assumption to 1 in the result)...

Answer (score 2):

The result is not true as stated = one can only show (see comment by @Calvin or [my answer using convolution to another MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691605/for-all-p-in-0-1-there-is-a-constant-mp-such-that-fzmp-exp-frac/3691693#3691693)) the result for any $0<p<1$ namely that under OP hypothesis there is $C(p)>0$ st:

$\left| \sum_{1}^\infty \frac{c_nz^n}{n!} \right| \le C(p) \cdot e^{|z|/(pR)}$

For example choose $c_0=c_1=0, c_n=n^{n/\log^2 n}, n \ge 2$; it is easy to see (taking logarithms) that $c_n^{1/n} \to 1$ so the radius of convergence of $\sum_{0}^\infty c_nz^n$ is $1$ but if we assume there is a $C>0$ for which:

$\left| \sum_{1}^\infty \frac{c_nz^n}{n!} \right| \le C \cdot e^{|z|}$ we take $z=m$ and by positivity of the coefficients we have:

$\frac{c_mm^m}{m!} < \left| \sum_{1}^\infty \frac{c_nm^n}{n!} \right| \le C \cdot e^{m}$

This gives: $m^{m/\log^2 m}m^m<Cm!e^m \le Cem^m\sqrt m e^{-m}e^m$ by an easy inequality that follows from Stirling approximatiom, which reduces to:

$m^{m/\log^2 m} < Ce \sqrt m$  and that is not possible for arbitrary large $m$ since $m/\log^2m \to \infty$ hence $m^{m/\log^2 m}/\sqrt m \to \infty$.

(It is instructive to see how this counterexample fails when we have $e^{m/p}, 0<p<1$ on RHS rather than $e^m$)

Comment: the idea is that if $f$ is analytic with some radius of convergence we can say something about the entire function $f*e^z$ (when $R$ is positive finite we can say that $f*e^z$ is of exponential type $1/R$ and when $R=\infty$ we can say that $f$ is of minimal $(1,0)$ type; when $R=0$ we can say nothing however in the sense that $f*e^z$ may still not converge anywhere, may be entire but of high order or anything in-between)